# Flutter - Issue working with SignInWithEmailAndPassword() within Google_Sign_In package

Tags: dart, flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies

I'm still getting my feet wet with Flutter and i'm looking for a simple way to implement a Login Form plus Google Sign In button. I have manage to get both working independently (on different apps) but i would like to combine the two into a single 'Auth' object.

The best example i've found was using the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in) (v3.2.2) package which i've successfully implemented the 'google sign in' functionality. So the next step is to have the option for the user to create an account and use a normal login form to authenticate their account (cause not every has a google account). The normal login form will reference Firebase's Authentication Service.

So i noticed the package contains a method called `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

Which can be called with the following code

```
Future<Null> _handleFireBaseSignIn() async {
  await Auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'tester');
}
```

Which is a copy of the google authenticate function which is being called as follows:

```
Future<Null> _handleSignIn() async {
  await Auth.signIn();
}
```

Yet hard coded the email/password which was required by the method for authentication. Please note: I had previously set up an account on firebase with test@test.com/tester credentials.

Both options now Authenticate the user. Outputted by - `print('Email: - ' + Auth.email);`

The examples then uses builds the page dependant on if the _currentUser is not null:

```
Widget _buildBody() {
  if (_currentUser != null) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

And this is where i'm getting stuck. Firstly i'm not sure if i should be trying to populate the _currentUser variable (which is has a `GoogleSignInAccount` Type) or should i be referencing a new variable which i can check against in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a getCurrentUser function that would allow you to populate the currentUser variable.